# Why isn't my code accepted as correct for "Sum of Factors" in SPOJ

Tags: c++, logic

Please check [this question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CZ_PROB2/)("Sum of Factors") and [similar question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/DIVSUM/)("Divisor Summation")

My below code is accepted as correct answer for "Divisor Summation" problem but getting "wrong answer" status for "Sum of Factors" problem.

The commented return statement is used for "Divisor Summation" problem.

Could someone identify what could be the possible mistake? Am I missing some testcase? Please help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double getFactorSum(long num){
    double factorsSum = 0;
    long i;
    for (i = 1; i <= (num / i); i++ ){
        if ((num % i) == 0){
            factorsSum += ((num / i) == i ? 0 : (num / i)) + i;
        }
    }
    //return factorsSum - num;
    return factorsSum;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int numTestCases;
    cin >> numTestCases;

    while (numTestCases--){
        long input;
        cin >> input;
        cout << getFactorSum(input) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: AFAICS, the line `factorsSum += ((num / i) == i ? 0 : (num / i)) + i;` will add 3 to the sum when `num` is given the value 2 (and `i` is 1).  That looks suspicious to me.

Comment: Print each item you think it a factor before adding it to the summation. The problem will become obvious fairly quickly. And remember the requirements include both 1 and the number itself in the summation, so no matter what the number is so long as it is greater than one it will have a *minimum * summation of `num+1`. You may want to validate that as well.

Comment: you're right and that is supposed to happen. The factor sum of 2 are (1,2). So 1+2 = 3 should be the result

Comment: @WhozCraig: I did what you said. I assume that is why it got accepted for "Divisor summation" problem